# How can I throw an exception from inside a WCF custom MessageEncoder and return it to the client?

Tags: wcf, exception

In my WCF service I have implemented a custom encoder which inherits from `System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageEncoder`.

In that encoder, I take the raw message and manipulate the received headers in my override of the `ReadMessage()` method.

During this manipulation, I may sometimes detect something in the header which makes the message invalid, and I want to return a useful exception to the client.

I have tried:

```
throw new Exception("Some useful message");
```

And:

```
throw new FaultException("Some useful message");
```

They both return an HTTP 400 to the client with no response body.

I can happily throw a `FaultException` from my actual web service method and this is returned to the client correctly, but at that late stage of the processing I no longer have access to the SOAP headers (unless someone can tell me otherwise).

How can I return a response 500 to the client with a friendly message based on information in the SOAP header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call:

```
OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders
```

in your service method to inspect the headers there if you wish. A custom MessageEncoder seems to me the wrong beast to be using to do what you describe.

Comment: I take your point, but I have no choice but to inspect the headers at this early stage.  We are nationally mandated to implement a security scenario that WCF simply does not enable.  Saying that, doing the bare minimum in the encoder and raising the exceptions using your method would seem to be a good solution.